# javascript get innerHTML of $('#madiv')[i]

Tags: javascript, jquery, selector

As the title mention i have a jquery request to get an element

but when i do this

```
cmdState = $('.commande>.entete_commande>.content>#statut')[i]
```

I can't do `cmdState.html()` to get the innerHTML

I obtain `<div id="statut">Send</div>` But what I want is only the html the "Send" char but when I do `.html()`, I got an error.

Do you have a solution ??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

id is a unique

```
       $('#statut').html();
```

`$('.commande>.entete_commande>.content>#statut')[i]` will return java script object not jquery , so you can use eq()

```
 $('.commande>.entete_commande>.content>.statut').eq(i);
                                        ^^^^use common class here
```